# CSS How to make an ul>li stairs effect

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need a simple *unordered list* with each next child `li` having an auto-incremented margin-left. Finally this should look like:

[image: stairs-like unordered list] (and etc infinitely...)

I know that it can be realized by simple nesting the elements one inside the other infinitely or manually setting the margin-left on each next `li` element incremented by some value. But I wanna try solving this without these workarounds, but on native css only.

The only idea I had - is to create in `li` an `:after` pseudo, that is positioned relatively inside of parent `li` and overflows it by left-bottom corner, so, that pseudo also overlaps the next sibling `li` element (both the `li` and it's `:after` pseudo should have `float: left;` property). But that didn't work. All I've got - is that pseudo-element overflows it's parent and overlaps the next sibling li, so the floating doesn't work. I have no possible reasons why. Do you have any idea?

Comment: To make this not a total pain I think you'd have to use something like SASS. Otherwise you'll need to set up :nth-child or :nth-of-types for as many items as you can foresee existing.

Comment: Is there a particular reason/goal for trying to make this on a single list? What you describe as 'workarounds' are more semantically correct - a single-level collection of <li> elements at different indentations is semantically kinda weird.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/34r570qt/, based on @Ben comment

Comment: @Ben, the stairs-like list is created on page dynamically by script (1). I also have a mobile view for current layout, in which case the stairs should be hidden, and each next `li` should start with the same margin (2). In this case I should unwrap each ul to make the DOM structure 1-leveled, but if using some CSS solution, I simply can change a classname (or event use the `@media` query), and the problem is gonna be solved without javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the visual effect you want using css shapes:

[Note that support is currently limited](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes)

Example

```css
div {
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 0 200px, 200px 300px);
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

span {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span>item</span>
<span>item</span>
<span>item</span>
<span>item</span>
<span>item</span>
```

[More information](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/)

Comment: Great, thanks! But CSS shapes are unsupported by most browsers on today. May be there is some cross-browser solution?

Comment: @impulsgraw I don't think there's a cross browser solution using Shapes. I did have another way of approaching this problem, I will update the answer later